# How to append to the end of each line?

Tags: text-processing

I have this file, `ipaddresses.txt`

```
152.48.64.13
146.112.164.43
236.157.219.229
188.201.225.93
193.140.79.73
...
```

And this file, `cidr.txt`

```
20
21
8
20
21
...
```

And I want the output file to be like this:

```
152.48.64.13/20
146.112.164.43/21
236.157.219.229/8
188.201.225.93/20
193.140.79.73/21
...
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why `sed`, specifically? have you considered alternatives - such as `paste -d/ ipaddresses.txt cidr.txt` ?

Comment: Because I only know `sed` to do this kind of task, I will edit my thread. By the way, I tried using `paste`, it doesn't append to the last line, but it append a new line each.

Comment: @Annahri The `paste` command by steeldriver works. Do you not have GNU `paste` or is there something with your environment such as an alias?

Comment: @NasirRiley I'm using bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 (what is the correct term for this?)  I did `paste -d/ ipaddresses.txt cidr.txt > out.txt`. When I try to do it without outputting a file, It prints a different behaviour. It adds \ in the beginning of each line but It does correctly for the very last line. Hmm

Comment: @Annahri do your files have Windows style (CRLF) line endings by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver How can I verify it?

Comment: You can use the `file` command (`file cidr.txt`) or for example `cat` with the `-v` option (`cat -v cidr.txt`) that will display CR as `^M`

Comment: I did `cat -v out.txt`, and apparently, It wraps each line from `cidr.txt` with `^M`. For example, `185.120.53.124^M/28^M`. But for the very last line, it has no `^M` "wrapping". Strange. Any clue?

Comment: I see, my files have `^M` line endings except for the last line.

Comment: The command `dos2unix` should be able to help you strip the carriage returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`paste`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html):

```
$ paste -d '/' ipaddresses.txt cidr.txt
152.48.64.13/20
146.112.164.43/21
236.157.219.229/8
188.201.225.93/20
193.140.79.73/21
.../...
```